# document.write become invalid within Javascript file which is added by appendChild

Tags: javascript, appendchild, document.write, createelement

when I add the script tag in body tag of my index.html **directly**, like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='**doc_write_in_it.js**'></script>
```

It works well, the "test doc write" is output there.

But if I write **in another way**, like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = document.createElement('script');
    model.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    model.setAttribute('src','doc_write_in_it.js');
    var bd = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    bd.appendChild(model);
</script>
```

document.write become invalid within Javascript file which is added by appendChild.

The alert in **doc_write_in_it.js** will show, but the text in document.write doesn't.

**doc_write_in_it.js** file is like this:

```
alert('activited');
document.write('test doc write");
```

Hope someone can help...
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: did you try adding onload around your code or having is last before the body closes?

Comment: I'd tried to put it in a function, but the result is the same, 'alert' show itself or 'console.log' show itself, except 'document.write'

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above, document.write does not work when the page has already been loaded.
I suggest use innerHTML property whenever you can.

example:

```
var bd = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
bd.innerHTML = "some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write will overwrite anything else before it. So, if you are absolutely sure that it is what you want to be doing. Then you should probably wait for the page to load, and then fire the document.write. Something on the lines of the below..

```
<script>
function my_onload_fn() {
    document.write("test document write");
}
</script>

<body onload="my_onload_fn();">
```

Comment: In my case, the 'document.write' seems deactivated or for some other reasons, it doesn't output anything, even if I put it in window.onload function.

Comment: @auCrux so what do you see? does the alert show up? and document.write doesn't.. or none of them execute?

Comment: @auCrux in the doc_write_in_it.js, put the alert and document.write in a function.. and call that function onload on the html page. i am wondering if the document.write is overwriting the page even before anything else can happen...

Comment: I'd tried to put it in a function, but the result is the same, 'alert' show itself or 'console.log' show itself, except 'document.write'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `document.write` can't affects when page is loaded, but you can invoke `document.open()` to make it posible.

Putting script code in `script` tag is synchronous, while loading script file via DOM manipulation is asynchronous, so,if the page is simple, page may have been loaded when `document.write(..)` runs and make `document.write(...)` do nothing if `document.open()` is not invoked.

```
alert('activited');
document.open();
document.write('test doc write');
document.close();
```

This will work.
And check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) to learn more.